# What is the relationship between these two topologies?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}^\prime$ be two topologies on a set $X$ such that either $\mathcal{T}\subset \mathcal{T}^\prime$ or $\mathcal{T}^\prime \subset \mathcal{T}$ and such that $X$ is compact and Hausdorff under both $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}^\prime$. Is there any  relationship between $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}^\prime$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equal. Suppose $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal T'$. Then the identity map $(X, \mathcal T') \to (X, \mathcal T)$ is continuous and bijective. As $(X, \mathcal T')$ is compact and $(X, \mathcal T)$ is Hausdorff, it is also closed, hence a homeomorphism. So $\mathcal T = \mathcal T'$.

Comment: Also note that any topology strictly finer than $\mathcal{T}$ is Hausdorff but not compact and any strictly coarser topology is compact but not Hausdorff so compact Hausdorff is some kind of balance.